# Apache Spark 2.1 - Scala Lengthy/Heavy attributes for Row Object

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, apache-spark-2.0

We have written a spark application in Scala 2.11 which runs on Spark 2.1.0 standalone cluster. As per design/requirements, we have constructed row object having lot of direct columns like 100's and there are few nested columns where some of nested columns are also heavy like having 20k to 30k of Sequence. There is also matching case class to work with Spark datasets.

**For eg:**

```
Row(column_01,
    column_02...
    .....column_150, 
        column_151 = Seq,
        column_152 = Seq...column_160 = Seq)
```

where some of Seq are having size of 20k to 30k.

I am little concerned about how does this lengthy/heavy attributes for a row object affects performance? What are the optimizations we can do on code to improve performance? Any suggestions for cluster tuning?

We are already working on the following optimizations -

1. increasing the # of partitions
2. Using parquet file format with snappy compression

Answer (score 1):

Spark has no particular problems with heavy rows. We manage petabytes of data in deeply nested rows with hundreds of fields without problems.

There are a few things to keep in mind:

1. Where possible, prefer structs over maps as structs are automatically flattened in Parquet and maps are more complex to instantiate.
2. If you need to process all the data in a row most of the time and can use datasets exclusively, you'll typically get better performance than using dataframes and it's worth investing in the case classes to enable the dataset encoding/decoding.
3. For queries that only need a little bit of the data, run `df.explain()` to see if Spark is not pulling too much, e.g., an entire struct when only one field of the struct is needed. At the time of this writing, there are some problems with that. One can usually work around them by rewriting the transformation/query to explicitly select the minimal set of data needed first.
4. Avoid nested arrays where possible as their processing can gets complicated. Arrays by themselves are not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using parquet which is columnar so you can use dataframe syntax to select only those columns you need to process and operate on them. If you use dataset using ‘dataframe.as[class]’ syntax then deserialized the whole row which can be expensive if there are too columns. You can select few column using dataset also but you would need to cast it into a class which has those properties.